# Python printing format with functions

Tags: python, function, printing, stdstring

I am currently learning Python and have written this basic function. However the output is on several lines and does not show the answer after the "Here is some math:". What is wrong?

Thank you

```
def ink(a, b):
    print "Here is some math:"
    return a + b        
add = ink(1, 59)    
fad = ink(2, 9)    
bad = ink(4, 2)     
print add    
print fad    
print bad
```

Output :

```
Here is some math:
Here is some math:
Here is some math:
60
11
6
```

EDIT:
Why is it not printing

Output :

```
Here is some math:
60
Here is some math:
11
Here is some math:
6
```

Comment: Did you expect `return a+ b` to have printed the result? Or did you expect the execution of the function would be delayed untill - `print add` ?

Comment: No I expected the print add, print fad etc to print it, but why does it not display as
Here is some math:
60
Here is some math:
11

??

Comment: It is printing correctly, I do not understand what you are expecting from that code. Why would you expect that to happen? You are only printing the result of addition after calling all the functions.

Comment: I have added an edit sorry it was not clear before..

Comment: What's scenario behind this? I think also in other languages as Java or C++, print will be executed in that order~

Comment: @linpingta You must've misunderstood something, Java and C++ work just like Python in this scenario, as do almost all programming languages.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen , sorry, I didn't check question clearly, thanks for your remind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you call a function, its body gets executed *immediately*.
So when you call `add = ink(1, 59)`, the `ink` function's body, which contains a `print` statement, is executed.
Thus it prints out `"Here is some math:"`.

Once the function's body reaches a `return` statement, the function's execution will end and the `return` statement returns a value to the place where the function was called.
So when you you do:

```
add = ink(1, 59)
```

The `result` is returned by `ink(1, 59)`, then stored to `add`, but the `result` doesn't get printed yet.

You then repeat the same for other variables (`fad` and `bad`), which is why you get the printed `"Here is some math:"` three times before seeing any numbers.
Only later you print the actual results using:

```
print add
print fad
print bad
```

---

What you should do instead, is to have functions only calculate the results:

```
def ink(a, b):
    return a + b
```

And usually you'd want to do the prints and inputs outside of the functions (or in main function):

```
add = ink(1, 59)
fad = ink(2, 9)
bad = ink(4, 2)

print "Here's some math:", add
print "Here's some math:", fad
print "Here's some math:", bad
```

Although repeated code is often considered bad, so you could use a `for` loop here (you should study more about for loops if you don't know how they work):

```
for result in (add, fad, bad):
    print "Here's some math:", result
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, I understand that now :) Thank you!

Comment: @NZSteve Good to know it helped! I've updated the answer with a "proper" solution, if you're interested :)

Comment: Loops are a bit further ahead of me, but your explanation makes sense thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The function `ink` is printing `Here is some math:` when it's called, when its return value is assigned in

```
add = ink(1, 59)
```

And the result value is printed in

```
print add
```

To achieve what you want you would have to do

```
print ink(1, 59)
```

EDIT: Even better, if it's for debugging:

```
def ink(a, b):
    result = a + b
    print "Here is some math:"
    print result
    return result
```

Anyway, I believe that what you wrote here is only an example. You should not print anything from functions that calculate something if it's not for debugging purposes. If it is for debugging, then the entire message should be contained in the body of a function and not be split like that.

Comment: Ok thanks, so this couldnt be achieved by printing the variables? (Sorry i am new so trying to understand :) )

Comment: I'm not aware of a clean way to do it, that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Your answer `print ink(1, 59)` only prints the number, doesn't print the `"Here is some math:"`

Comment: @JoeR I believe it prints it as the function `ink` is called.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that by calling the function it executes the print.. I understand now :) cheers

Comment: You believe or you tested it?

Comment: Yes, it prints. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return` what you want to print:

```
def ink(a, b):
    return "Here is some math: {}".format(a + b)
add = ink(1, 59)
fad = ink(2, 9)
bad = ink(4, 2) 

print add
print fad
print bad
```

Output:

```
Here is some math: 60
Here is some math: 11
Here is some math: 6
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that will also work so will play with that too